# Why does git still print to the screen when both stdout and stderr have been redirected?

Tags: git, shell, command-line

I want to mute the output of a git push command used in my CI system which may leak sensitive information.

The command is:

`git --quiet push > /dev/null 2>&1`

so it should not print anything to the screen. But it still prints `Password for 'https://xxxx@github.com':` when auth fails.

How could this happen and how to mute it?

Update:
Though I am not sure, I guess git calls `getpass()` or something similar that writes to `/dev/tty` directly.

Comment: Reproduce here with this test `sleep 10 | nohup git clone --quiet https://git... >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 1):

To prevent key logging and work around redirects password prompt is done via `/dev/tty`. See how this is done in Python's [getpass](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6fe9c446f8302553952f63fc6d96be4dfa48ceba/Lib/getpass.py#L48).

Answer (score 1):

Git explicitly opens `/dev/tty` for reading *and* writing, which is used for the password prompt.

`/dev/tty` was added to Unix at around 1979, allowing programs to obtain a file descriptor to the controlling terminal, so user input was made possible when stdin is occupied, as well as when both stdout and stderr are redirected.

See [How does `less` take data from stdin while still be able to read commands from user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/452757/211239)